convert data seperated by comma into a vector
I am very new to python and what to write a scrip to convert long data into a vector.
I have a long data seperated by comma
Example :
Data =  [40,  86, 159, 178,  75, 126,  77,  
231,  73, 235, 168, 144, 206,  23, 182, 104]

I want this to be to become array of data such as:
data[16] = [40,  86, 159, 178,  75, 126,  77,231,  73, 235, 168, 144, 206,  23, 182, 104]

How to write this in python.
I tried in MATLAB but tis giving in matrix form due to enter.

Is it a string that your are trying to convert? Why are you using the term vector? Do you want the result to be a Numpy array rather than just a Python list? Where is the input coming from? Your question should be clearer

I guess its a List in Python from the way it looks

@Mo711 so what is the difference between the input and the output? I guess data[16] = ... was supposed to be an array definition like in C, rather than an assignment. The answer to this question as it currently appears should be a couple of topics from a Python course

@SomethingSomething Python just uses lists if you give it this format. Thats why I assume the data 'array' to be a numpy array, which can also be used as a vecotr in some calculations

Please explain what data[16] is supposed to represent. In purely Python terms it appears to be the 17th element of a list with a size of at least 17. Are you familiar with the distinction between lists and arrays in Python?

I would assume, that Data is a list. You can simply convert it to an numpy array
data = [40, 86, 159, 178, 75, 126, 77, 231, 73, 235, 168, 144, 206, 23, 182, 104]


data_array = np.array(data)

I dont know why you call it a vector though
